# Prove that the function $f:X\to I=[0,1]$ by $f(x)=\min\{\frac{d(x,C)}{d(p,C)},1\}$ is continuous on $X$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, separation-axioms

[image]

Question1. I can prove that Every metric space is Hausdorff. Where do they use this fact in this proof?

Question2. Let $C$ be a closed subset of $X$ and $p\in X\setminus C$. How do I prove the function $f:X\to I=[0,1]$ by $f(x)=\min\{\frac{d(x,C)}{d(p,C)},1\}$. How do I prove that $f$ is continuous?

**My attempt:-**
$g(x)=d(x,C)$ is a continuous function. Since, for $c\in C$, $d(x,c)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,c)\implies d(x,C)-d(x,y)\leq d(y,c)\implies d(x,C)-d(x,y)\leq d(y,C) \implies d(x,C)-d(y,C)\leq d(x,y) $  . From this inequality we can deduce that $g$ is continuous.  $d(p,C)\neq 0$ is constant. So,$\frac{d(x,C)}{d(p,C)}$ is continuous. The minimum of two continuous real-valued functions $u,v$ is continuous, since $\min \{u(x),v(x)\}=\frac{1}{2}(u(x)+v(x)-|u(x)-v(x)|)$. Hence, $f$ is continuous. Am I correct?

Comment: Your attempt at question 2 looks fine. As for question 1, how does the book you are quoting define "completely regular"?

Comment: I am taking the definition from Foundation of Topology by C.W Patty

Comment: Good work.....If $S$ is $any$ non-empty subset of $X$ then $g(x)=d(x,S)=\inf \{d(x,s):s\in S\}$ is continuous.....  The proof given in the book applies only for non-empty $C.$(Otherwise how do you define $d(p,C)$?), although the case $C=\phi$ is fairly trivial (i.e. let $f(x)=1$ for all $x \in X).$... I made an edit regarding the minimum  of two functions, without changing the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. I do not know which definition of "completely regular" is used in your textbook. If it means that any closed $C$ and any $x \notin C$ can be separated by a continuous function, then "Hausdorff" is irrelevant. However, many authors define 
"completely regular = Hausdorff + functional separation".

Comment: I am taking the definition from Foundation of Topology by C.W Patty

Comment: They are defining $T_1-$space$(X,\mathscr T)$ is completely regular provided continuous separion for Closed set and a point not lie in the closed set.

Comment: Then it must be explicitly stated in the proof that $X$ is $T_1$. Hausdorff implies $T_1$ and that is the reason why it is mentioned. Note that for a space with the functional separation property for a closed set and a point outside this set, $T_1$ implies Hausdorff.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101436/how-do-i-prove-the-fx-to-i-by-fx-min-f-ix-betai-1-2-n-is-co Can I do the question using similar here?